# Google Maps API v3: How to return marker colour to original when clicking another marker?

Tags: google-maps

I'm using an onclick event to change a marker image when it's clicked, to show that it's highlighted.

**When I click another marker, I would like this marker to return to the original image, rather than staying highlighted.**

Here is the code;

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   marker.setIcon("default_h.png")
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    document.getElementById("address_box").value = (title + "\n" + address);
 });
```

I imagine one way would be to create a rule somehow that only one highlighted image could be present on the map at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store a reference to the clicked marker somewhere, and then use setIcon.

So you code would look vaguely like this:

```
var highlighted;

//create your markers here and assign them event listeners
var markerObject = new google.maps.Marker({});
google.maps.event.addListener(markerObject,'click',function() {
 if(highlighted) {
  highlighted.setIcon(/* original icon */);
 }

 highlighted = markerObject;
 highlighted.setIcon(/* highlighted icon */);

});
```